# Error after Parse query from local datastore

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com library and I want to query from local datastore if user lost access to internet (query on pinned items from previous app usage). Problem is that if use offline query it will not return `List<Object>` but weird `AbstractList` and I don't know how to convert it to ArrayList.

Anyone had this issue?

API call:

```
fun getFilteredObjects(c: Context, searchQuery: String?, filteredObjectsCallback: (ArrayList<ParseObject>?, ParseException?) -> Unit){
            val q = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>(OBJECT_CLASS)
            if (!isOnline(c)) q.fromLocalDatastore()

            if (searchQuery.isNullOrEmpty()){
                q.limit = 10
            } else {
                q.whereMatches(OBJECT_NAME, searchQuery, "i")
            }

            q.findInBackground { objectList, err ->
                filteredObjectsCallback(objectList as ArrayList<ParseObject>?, err)
            }
        }
```

Error line: `filteredObjectsCallback(objectList as ArrayList<ParseObject>?, err)`

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractListRandomAccess cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cast is invalid because types are not convertible: `objectList` is of type `AbstractList` and that cannot be hard casted to `ArrayList` like that.

Instead, use `Arrays.asList(objectList)`, I think it has its own implementation and translates the abstract list.